# OneNote error creating a page in Laravel using Microsoft Graph

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

i'm using Microsoft Graph in my Laravel application.
It works perfectly adding events to the user's calendar, getting events, creating OneNote's notebook.
The problem occurs when i try to add a page, i'm getting the next error:
[image]
The code i'm using is:

```
public function createNewNote()
    {
        $graph = $this->getGraph();

        // Build the event
            $newEvent = [
                'body' => [
                    'content' => 'New page in default notebook',
                    'contentType' => 'text/html'
                ]
            ];
            // POST /me/onenote/notebooks DEFAULT NOTEBOOK
            $response = $graph->createRequest('POST', '/me/onenote/pages')
                ->attachBody($newEvent)
                ->setReturnType(Model\Notebook::class)
                ->execute();
            dd("Success");
//            return redirect('/calendar');
    }
```

The next code works fine:

```
public function createNewNotebook()
    {
        $graph = $this->getGraph();
        
            $newEvent = [
                'displayName' => 'Creating new notebook'
            ];
            // POST /me/onenote/notebooks DEFAULT NOTEBOOK
            $response = $graph->createRequest('POST', '/me/onenote/notebooks')
                ->attachBody($newEvent)
                ->setReturnType(Model\Notebook::class)
                ->execute();
            dd("Notebook Created");
//            return redirect('/calendar');
    }
```

I can't find the exact array or json structure for the body. What am i doing wrong? I also tried setting the text directly:

```
public function createNewNote()
    {
        $graph = $this->getGraph();
            // POST /me/onenote/notebooks DEFAULT NOTEBOOK
            $response = $graph->createRequest('POST', '/me/onenote/pages')
                ->attachBody('<div>Content</div>')
                ->setReturnType(Model\Notebook::class)
                ->execute();
            dd("Success");
//            return redirect('/calendar');
    }
```

And getting this error:

[![enter image description here][1]][2]

As i said i can create events (calendar) and notebooks (onenote) but i can't add a page with simple html or text.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please share the whole error response with requestid and timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onenote-post-pages?view=graph-rest-1.0#request) since you are putting the HTML data in `attachBody` directly without specifying the content type.

That's the reason the other API calls work as they have JSON data specified properly.

As specified here in the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onenote-post-pages?view=graph-rest-1.0#example) they have specified the content type.

I have tested the same with POSTMAN as shown below where you can see the content-type I have mentioned as `text/html` as the content we give is a div tag and it worked.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I used Guzzle and it's working great!
Have a great day!

Comment: @Kashorako Glad to here that it worked for you :)-